# How do I avoid unwrap when converting a vector of Options or Results to only the successful values?

Tags: rust, iterator

I have a `Vec<Result<T, E>>` and I want to ignore all `Err` values, converting it into a `Vec<T>`. I can do this:

```
vec.into_iter().filter(|e| e.is_ok()).map(|e| e.unwrap()).collect()
```

This is safe, but I want to avoid using `unwrap`. Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> I want to ignore all `Err` values

Since [`Result` implements `IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-IntoIterator), you can convert your `Vec` into an iterator (which will be an iterator of iterators) and then flatten it:

- [`Iterator::flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten):

  ```
  vec.into_iter().flatten().collect()
  ```
- [`Iterator::flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map):

  ```
  vec.into_iter().flat_map(|e| e).collect()
  ```

These methods also work for [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html), which [also implements `IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-IntoIterator-2).

---

You could also convert the `Result` into an `Option` and use  [`Iterator::filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map):

```
vec.into_iter().filter_map(|e| e.ok()).collect()
```

Comment: Hallelujah! Just learned about `filter_map()`. I used it successfully like so: `let mut lines: Vec<String> = reader.lines().filter_map(|l| l.ok() ).collect();`. To make sure I understand, `filter_map` converts options returned by `Result`'s `ok()` method if they are `Ok(T)` and skips that item of the iterator if it's an `Err`? Thanks so much.

Comment: @PeterCharland more or less. But why use that instead of the shorter versions shown in the answer?

Comment: I guess I still don't get why into_iter returns a 2d iterator.