# How to aggregate iterators over errors when using filter_map with a fallible mapping function?

Tags: error-handling, rust, iterator

Suppose I want to read all files in a directory. I might define a function like this:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs;
use std::io;

type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>;

fn read_entry(entry: io::Result<fs::DirEntry>) -> Result<Option<String>> {
    let entry = entry?;
    if entry.file_type()?.is_file() {
        Ok(Some(fs::read_to_string(entry.file_name())?))
    } else {
        Ok(None)
    }
}
```

And then try to use it...

```
use std::path::Path;

fn read_all(dir: &Path) -> Result<Vec<String>> {
    Ok(fs::read_dir(dir)?
        .filter_map(|entry| read_entry(entry).unwrap())
        .collect())
}
```

This compiles but it just `unwrap()`s errors. `collect()` normally can aggregate iterators over errors but I can't quite figure out how to do this with `filter_map()`. How can I fix this?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ecbdae3ebe9c6ec368757fd46b0242e1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I avoid unwrap when converting a vector of Options or Results to only the successful values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020110/how-do-i-avoid-unwrap-when-converting-a-vector-of-options-or-results-to-only-the)

Comment: No. I do not want to ignore errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a nice [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA%2C%20E%3E%3E) of `FromIterator` for `Iter<Item = Result>` (which is an underlying trait for `Iterator::collect`), so this works:

```rust
fn read_all(dir: &Path) -> Result<Vec<String>> {
    fs::read_dir(dir)?
        .filter_map(|entry| read_entry(entry).transpose())
        .collect()
}
```

Comment: Aha `transpose()` was the missing link! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `Result<Option<T>>` you need `Option<Result<T>>`, i.e. before:

- `Ok(Some(T))`: It was a file and we read it successfully
- `Ok(None)`: It wasn't a file but we didn't have any errors finding that out.
- `Err`: There was an error.

After:

- `Some(Ok(T))`: It was a file and we read it successfully
- `None`: It wasn't a file but we didn't have any errors finding that out.
- `Some(Err)`: There was an error.

You can change the original implementation but then it means that you can't use the `?` operator, which sucks.

A better solution - as @Kitsu pointed out is to use the built in function [`transpose()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.transpose) which will convert a `Result<Option<T>>` into an `Option<Result<T>>`.

Comment: Agree, moreover I would even change the `read_entry` argument to `entry: fs::DirEntry`, then it can be used without an additional closure, i.e. `.filter_map(read_entry)`

Comment: But `read_dir()` returns an iterator over `Result<fs::DirEntry>`s... ?

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion, the reason the `read_entry` fails is because is using `entry.file_name()` instead of `entry.path()`.

So this:

```
Ok(Some(fs::read_to_string(entry.file_name())?))
```

should be:

```
Ok(Some(fs::read_to_string(entry.path())?))
```