# How to convert a vector of options to a simple vector in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust, option-type

Let's assume I have a `Vec` containing optional boxes of a struct called 'Dummy'.

```rust
struct Dummy {
    foo: i32
}

fn main() {
    let a = Box::new(Dummy {foo: 42});
    let b = Box::new(Dummy {foo: 69});
    let c = Box::new(Dummy {foo: 420});

    let bar = vec![Some(a), None, Some(b), None, Some(c)];

    // This works, but it's a lot of calls for a single task.
    let only_elements: Vec<&Box<Dummy>> = bar.iter()
        .filter(|&el| el.is_some())
        .map(|el| el.as_ref().unwrap())
        .collect();

    for el in only_elements {
        println!("{}", el.foo);
    }
}
```

How can I convert this `Vec` of options to a simple `Vec` of references in a prettier manner?
I wrote the only way I could come up to, but it looks a bit tedious for a thing that appears trivial to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I avoid unwrap when converting a vector of Options or Results to only the successful values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020110/how-do-i-avoid-unwrap-when-converting-a-vector-of-options-or-results-to-only-the)

Comment: I'm afraid I would need more details, since I'm already using an Option and not using a Result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter_map`. It removes at least one line from what you have. You can also use `turbofish` and the underscore for type specification in `collect::<Vec<_>>` so that you don't need to explicitly declare the type in case you want to change the mapping.

```rust
let only_elements = bar.iter()
        .filter_map(Option::as_ref)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

You can read more about `filter_map` from [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map).

---

As mentioned by @Masklinn and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020110/how-do-i-avoid-unwrap-when-converting-a-vector-of-options-or-results-to-only-the), `Option` implements `IntoIterator` so you can also use `flatten` for `Option` as you would for `Result`.

```rust
let only_elements = bar.iter().flatten().collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Comment: We can write this slightly differently too. Since in the original code the type of `only_elements` is specified, we can ommitt that here, and we can use `Option::as_ref` - Which gives `let only_elements: Vec<_> = bar.iter().filter_map(Option::as_ref).collect()`; (Which rustfmt is happy to keep on one line)

Comment: ^Updated to include part of your suggestion. I prefer to leave `Vec<_>` with the `collect` since my editor uses rust-analyzer which displays the type automatically.

Comment: @ToninGuy3n because `Option` implements `IntoIterator`, `flatten` will actually do the job you're using `filter_map(Option::as_ref)` for.