# Cryptic message when dealing with Rust Option type

Tags: rust

I have a function like the following:

```
pub fn process_options<T>(in_refs:& mut Vec<T>,ivals:Vec<Option<T>>) -> i32 {
    let mut nones = 0;
    for int in 0..ivals.len() {
        if let None = ivals[int] {
            nones += 1;
        } else {
            
            in_refs.push(ivals[int].unwrap());
        }
    }

    return nones;
}
```

What this function does is that it:
It pushes all the some(T) from one vector to another as T. And it also records the number of none values in the first vector. As written above the code fails to compile and gives me:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Option<T>>`
   --> src/functions.rs:40:26
    |
40  |             in_refs.push(ivals[int].unwrap());
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^ -------- value moved due to this method call
    |                          |
    |                          help: consider calling `.as_ref()` or `.as_mut()` to borrow the type's contents
    |                          move occurs because value has type `Option<T>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    |
note: this function takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves value
   --> /Users/yunfeichen/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/option.rs:772:25
    |
772 |     pub const fn unwrap(self) -> T {
```

Which I frankly do not understand can you explain this to me?

Edit:
This question has been solved:
It turns out I just need to use a different style of for loop, Not sure why this for loop works but it does:

```
pub fn process_options<T>(in_refs:& mut Vec<T>,ivals:Vec<Option<T>>) -> i32 {
    let mut nones = 0;
    for element in ivals{
        if let None = element {
            nones += 1;
        } else {
            in_refs.push(element.unwrap());
        }
    }

    return nones;
}
```

Comment: Vectors own their contents.  Unwrapping something it owns onto something else is trying to take it away.

Comment: So the easy way to fix this would be to?

Comment: The easiest way to fix this would be to use iterators and avoid the problem entirely. It looks like what you are trying to do is equivalent to `in_refs.extend(ivals.into_iter().filter_map(|x|x))`.

Comment: Turn it into an iter and then something like `filter_map`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68433373/how-to-convert-a-vector-of-options-to-a-simple-vector-in-rust

Comment: @Locke thank you, I think I fixed it by changing the for loop.

Comment: @Locke Better `in_refs.extend(ivals.into_iter().flatten())`;