# Idiomatic way to only get insides of `Some` from a vector of options?

Tags: vector, rust, iteration

I'm learning Rust and am trying to get used to working with `Result`s and `Option`s. Given a vector of either. If i only want the results that did not err (or aren't none for `Option`), is there a more graceful way of doing this than below or is this about the amount of boilerplate i'd have to usually write?

I realize there are a lot more granular that one can do in `map` like `unwrap_or_else` and `partition` good results away from bad.

```rust
    let optvec   = vec![Some(1), None, Some(4), None];
    let filtered = optvec.iter()
    .filter(|q| q.is_some())
    .map(|q| q.unwrap())
    .collect::<Vec<i32>>();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I avoid unwrap when converting a vector of Options or Results to only the successful values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020110/how-do-i-avoid-unwrap-when-converting-a-vector-of-options-or-results-to-only-the)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) it only returns the Somes not the Nones.

```rust
let optvec   = vec![Some(1), None, Some(4), None];
let filtered: Vec<i32> = optvec.iter().filter_map(|f| *f).collect();
println!("{:?}", filtered);
>>> [1, 4]
```

Comment: you can also just `.flatten()` since `Option<T>` also implements `Iterator<Item=T>`

Answer (score 4):

In your case since you are not doing any mapping, I would suggest using `flatten`ing instead of `filter_map`ing.
Which in my opinion is much clearer and more self explanatory.

```rust
    let optvec = vec![Some(1), None, Some(4), None];
    let filtered: Vec<i32> = optvec.iter().flatten().cloned().collect();
    assert_eq!(filtered, &[1, 4]);
```